# Check if an array element is in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am writing a bash script to check if an array element is in a file.

For example:

I have an array of errors `errors=("1234" "5678" "9999")`

I have a file that contains patterns of strings

`123400 452612 9999A0 1010EB`

I am looking to loop over the file that contains the errors and check to see if any of the array elements matches any string pattern in the file. If it does then give me back the exact array pattern it matched in the file for further processing.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: There are multiples lines in the file ? (or) just a single line with those fixed patterns?

Comment: Can the errors appear anywhere in the file?

Comment: The errors can appear anywhere in the file. The file contains multiple lines it has no fixed length.

Comment: For example: if `1234` matches you need the entire line `123400 452612 9999A0 1010EB` or just `123400`

Comment: If array element 1234 matches 123400 in the file then I need 1234 back for processing.

Comment: Are you going to show us the code you wrote to try and do this?

Comment: Thanks all for your help

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script goes like this,

```
#/bin/bash
errors=("1234" "5678" "9999")

for error in "${errors[@]}"
do
     grep -o "$error" file
done
```

For a sample file,

```
$ cat file
123400 452612 9999A0 1010EB
```

The script produces an output

```
$ ./script.sh
1234
9999
```

meaning the above two keys from the array have matched in the file. The `-o` flag in `grep` is to identify only the matching parts from the array. An excerpt from the `man grep` page.

```
-o, --only-matching
         Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
```

Comment: Thanks Inian. Just what I'm looking for

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way where you only need to invoke `grep` once:

```
$ grep -oFf <(printf "%s\n" "${errors[@]}") file
1234
9999
```

The `-f` option is to specify a file that contains the pattern. I use a process substitution to "contain" the patterns, one per line.

The `-F` option specifies plain-text matching: I assume your "errors" array won't contain regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just want a loop:

```
for error in "${errors[@]}"; do
    if grep -qE "(^| )$error( |\$)" file; then
        # $error was found in the file
    fi
done
```

This matches the error preceded by the start of the line or a space, and followed by a space or the end of the line.

I made an effort to *not* match appearances of the errors within substrings but if you don't care, then you could change the grep command to this:

```
grep -qF "$error" file
```

This will return success if the error string occurs anywhere on the line.